# Orient-DB delete edge

Tags: graph, orientdb

I'm new to Orient-DB and am a little confused as to why I can't delete an edge.

I've created two classes: `Tag` (extends V) and `parent` (extends E). I've populated with 3 sample tags.

[image: Sample Data]

I've then created an edge between #18:1 and #18:0 using the following command, this works as expected

`create edge parent from #18:1 to #18:0`

[image: Sample Data with Edges]

However if I then try and delete the edge with the following command nothing seems to change. The result of the command is

`delete edge parent from #18:1 to #18:0`

**Documentation:** https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Delete-Edge

[image: delete edge parent from #18:1 to #18:0]

Even if I use Orient-DB studio to delete the edge nothing changes. I do this by going to one of the records expanding the incoming/outgoing edges, pressing the X and confirming.

The only way I was able to delete it was to delete the edge from the `parent` class with

`delete from parent where @rid=#19:0`

However this won't work if I use lightweight edges. I'm using OrientDB community 1.7-rc1 as a standalone server on Windows 8.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your bug is known and it will be fixed tomorrow: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2035